# Using naming convention in directory instead of filename

Tags: flyway

1. Can we use the naming convention as part of directory instead of filename?

   e.g.

   ```
    /R1/1.0.1.0/
         user1_install.sql
         user2_install.sql
    /R1/1.0.2.0/
         user1_install.sql
         user2_install.sql
   ```

   1. For each version, is it possible to execute scripts using two different users e.g. user1 to execute user1_install.sql and user2 to execute user2_install.sql, before proceeding to deploy the next version?

Regds,

Ruck

Answer (score 0):

This is not currently supported. The version number has to be embedded in the filename (you can repeat it in the directory if you wish).

Also one instance of Flyway is associated with a datasource and its specific user. You can however run multiple Flyway instances (each with their own user) if you wish.